# Specific Java inheritance inquiry - Need suggestions

Tags: java, inheritance

The problem I am having is quite specific, and a bit difficult to explain. Let me know if you need more details about anything. I have an abstract class called `System`. To hold my `System` objects, I have a `SystemManager` which contains an list of `System`s, and some functions for manipulating it. Inside it contains:

```
List<System> systems = new ArrayList<System>();
```

Now, I want to create another abstract class which is a specific type of `System` called `RenderSystem`. This will inherit from `System` but have a few more functions. I also want to create a `RenderSystemManager` which should do everything `SystemManager` does, except with a few extra features. Also, instead of having a list of `System` in the manager, I would like it to have a list of `RenderSystem` to ensure that the programmers don't put any regular `System` objects in it. My initial instinct was to inherit `SystemManger`, and just change the type of the list to `RenderSystem`:

```
systems = new ArrayList<RenderSystem>();
```

Java doesn't allow this as systems is type `System` not `RenderSystem`. I would have assumed it would be OK considering `RenderSystem` inherits from `System`. One way I can think of to resolve this issue is to copy and paste all the code from `SystemManager` into `RenderSystemManager` and just change the line of code to be:

```
List<RenderSystem> systems = new ArrayList<RenderSystem>();
```

My other instinct would be to override the `addSystem(System system)` function to ensure that it only handles `RenderSystem`, but the programmers might think they are allowed to do it even if it doesn't work.

```
@Override
public void addSystem(System system)
{
    if (system instanceof RenderSystem)
    {
        super.addSystem(system);
    }
}
```

These doesn't seem very elegant though. Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: It appears your idea of `RenderSystemManager` violates the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), as a `SystemManager` allows adding `System`s but its alleged subtype doesn't.

Comment: Consider changing name of your `System` class to something different to avoid conflict with `java.lang.System` class.

Comment: Agreed with @delnan. The LSP wikipedia page may be a bit obtuse, though. *Basically*, it states subclasses should not *remove* features from superclasses, which is what your proposed design does. I suggest you consider JB Nizet's solution below.

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah, in my actual code I call it EntitySystem. Just thought I would shorten it for the example. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your managers have the same type-safety requirements as the list they wrap. They should thus follow the same strategy, and be generic types:

```
public class BaseSystemManager<T extends System> {
    private List<T> systems = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addSystem(T system) {
        systems.add(system);
    }

    // common methods
}

public class SystemManager extends BaseSystemManager<System> {
    // methods specific to System handling
}

public RenderSystemManager extends BaseSystemManager<RenderSystem> {
    // methods specific to RenderSystem handling
}
```

Comment: Perfect. EXACTLY what I was looking for! I've never used this before, but it will actually come in useful for a few other things I am doing. Thank you VERY much. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think your second instinct to add protection into the addSystem call is the correct one. That way SystemManager can still operate on the list of Systems. However I would change the implementation of addSystem to instruct developers in the proper usage:

```
@Override
public void addSystem(System system)
{
    if (system instanceof RenderSystem)
    {
        super.addSystem(system);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only RenderSystem objects can be added to a RenderSystemManager");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SystemManager could have a a list of System objects, and the list could be private, and the only way to add an object to that list would be a function that only took a RenderSystem as an argument.  You're trying to manhandle generics into a use for which they probably are not appropriate.

But I think you have bigger problems.

I think this happens to many of us when we start trying to design "from the inside out", i.e., you are taking programming constructs and trying to string them together at a level of detail that ignores (or forgets) what the code is trying to do from a higher level.  It's like saying "I want a while loop inside a do loop that has a switch statement with try-catch-finally-whatever, but I don't want to nest all these damn braces."

Take a few steps back and think about the external functionality you want to accomplish, and progress in small steps through design and implementation details from there...